I cannot open a list of websites on my pc, all other devices on the network do without issues
All devices are on the home wifi network.
I've tried setting my dns to Cloudflare's in both ipv4 and ipv6. I've tried accessing the ip adresses directly which worked on other devices but not my PC. I've tried to reset netsh, flush dns, disabling ipv4 or ipv6, nothing works.
I can access facebook, google, telegram... But not twitch, duckduckgo or stackoverflow. I have no idea of how to debug this, I've tried everything I know.
I have tried using both an ethernet and a wifi connection. The problem clearly sith windows as pinging does not work either and leads to "Ping request could not find host" and with an ip address available from other devices "PING: transmit failed. General failure."
Edit : Running windows on failsafe but with network access did not change anything.
Edit : Here's the dns request response for https://stackoverflow.com, in case that can help.
Stackoverflow
Edit : Interestingly, I've noticed ping requests do not appear in wireshark. They are simply never sent out, it seems. It's like ipv4 is just completely broken for some reason.
Edit : Here's the list of resets I did :

netsh winsock reset
netsh int ip reset
netcfg -d
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /registerdns


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What "list"? Is this a list of l;inks? Can you be specific? What particular URL's? Can you reach them by IP address?

I mention multiple websites in the second paragraph. In the third paragraph, I mention trying to ping an ip address with the error message I get

I should also mention that turning off ipv6 completely kills any connectivity, so I'm reasonnably sure Windows' ipv6 handling is to blame here. I've update to make sure to have any fixes.

Well this just solved itself out of NOWHERE. Not a restart, nothing was going on. I'm dumbfounded.

I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved and does not require an answer
